# Do I have to reopen /dev/urandom every read?

Tags: c, linux, random, password-hash

I have a server running in a forever loop. Every once in a while the server has to execute the hashing of a password (more specifically, every time a user sign up to my service). The hashing algorithm needs a salt, 16 random bytes, which I read from `/dev/urandom`, as recommended by many.

So I thought: why not call `fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb")` only once at the start of the server and then call `fread` as I need?

The examples I found in the web usually shows `fread` immediately preceded by `fopen`. But isn't that expensive?

Comment: Even better: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html

Comment: I'd use [getentropy()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getentropy.3.html) instead these days, but you can do that. Might run into issues with stdio buffering, of course (I don't know if glibc treats device files specially) . `open()` and `read()` are generally better if you want to read from a random device.

Comment: fresh open or same handle will work. You save the overhead of `fopen` by keeping the handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/dev/urandom` is an interface to the kernel's entropy-driven random number generator.  It has a manual page, which you can find [online](https://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom) and probably also locally.  Opening it via `fopen()` has no documented effect on the data that subsequently can be read.  There is no documented limitation to a single read per open, nor would such a limit be plausible.

> So I thought: why not call `fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb")` only once at
>   the start of the server and then call `fread` as I need?

You may do so.  The main cost is that you permanently devote one of your process's limited number of open files to this purpose, but that might very well not be a problem for you.

> The examples I found in the web usually shows fread immediately preceded by fopen. But isn't that expensive?

Opening a file is comparatively expensive, especially with respect to already having it open and therefore doing nothing, but whether it is costly enough to matter depends on how frequently it is done, what else the program may be doing at or around the same time, and other factors.  I'm inclined to suppose that none of that is really a consideration for your web examples, however, for I judge that they are presented as they are at least partially for didactic purposes.  If you're writing an example then it's a lot easier and clearer to show the `fopen()` than to describe in words that the `FILE` you're using is connected to `/dev/urandom`.